# What does the Flipped Input option do in Cave Story+?

Tags: nintendo-switch, cave-story

In the options menu for Cave Story+ on Nintendo Switch, there is an option labeled **Flipped Input**. I didn't see an explanation in the game's manual and, as far as I'm aware, this option is not available in any other version of Cave Story.

**What does the Flipped Input option do?**

---

Screenshots for comparison:

**Cave Story+ (Nintendo Switch)**:

[image: Options - Cave Story+ Switch]

**Cave Story+ (Steam)**:

[image: Options - Cave Story+ Steam]

Comment: Did you actually try playing with the option on both settings? It seems like it would just change the bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Flipped Input** option swaps which buttons are used for jumping and shooting.

- **Off**: A-Jump; B-Fire; Y-Jump
- **On**: A-Fire; B-Jump; Y-Fire